# Laravel Intervention - get ImageMagick instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, imagemagick, intervention

I´m using laravels Intervention library to manipulate an image (width Imagemagick as driver). In this process I also have to do a perspective transform on the image and as Intervention doesn´t provide such an method I want to use Imagemagicks distortImage.
So, now my question: How do i get the Imagemagick instance of my current image out of Intervention (if possible). Right now I´m encoding the image as png via Intervention and read the image blob in an new ImageMagick instance - is there an better/easier way?

Answer (score 1):

use this function

```
$imagick = $image->getCore();
```

reference: http://image.intervention.io/api/getCore